# Does the silver badge count have a different font weight or size than the bronze one on MSE?

Tags: bug, design, badges, top-bar, fonts

I was looking at my badges here on MSE. It appears to me the silver badge count has a different font-weight / font-size then the bronze badge count and the reputation.

I tried looking at the sites CSS, but I'm no expert at that.

[image]

PS. in this screenshot the numbers look cut-off at the top, that's not how it is on my screen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, both are `normal`:

**Bronze:**

[image]

**Silver:**

[image]

The size is equal too; `12px` (that's somewhere further down the developer tools).

That the bronze one (and the gold one) *appear* to be bolder than the silver one is an optical illusion, just like the [checker shadow illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion) (though there are probably better examples).

Comment: You are indeed right. I zoomed to the highest level at which the badge count is still displayed (190% for me) Then there is no visual difference left.